# Select from a table in for loop

Tags: c#, sql, select

```
for (int i = 0; i < final_query.Length; i++)
{
   con.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT * fROM TableFFF WHERE Data="+final_query[i]);

   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      string PatientName = (string)rdr[" Data "];
   }
}
```

I got that error

> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

on this line

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the Connection to the SqlCommand

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT * fROM TableFFF WHERE Data="+final_query[i], con);
```

But there are other errors:

- The call to con.Open() should be outside of the For loop
- Use and reuse Parameters, not string concatenation

  ```
  con.Open();   
  SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT * fROM TableFFF WHERE Data=@data", con);   
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", 0); // Supposing final_query[i] is an Int32
  for (int i = 0; i < final_query.Length; i++)   
  {   
      cmd.Parameters["@data"].Value = final_query[i];   
      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();   
      while (rdr.Read())   
      {   
          string PatientName = (string)rdr[" Data "];   
      }   
  }
  ```

And it is still not clear what you are supposing to do with the PatientName after the first round

Comment: I will do another operation after that but i need to select first from the table

Answer (score 0):

You arnt telling the sqlcommand to use the connection con
try

```
SqlCommand("SELECT * fROM TableFFF WHERE Data="+final_query[i], con);
```

Though it seems this isnt very good coding, and could use some redesign....